# Modify SEXP in-place with Rcpp sugar

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

Consider a dummy example

```
> cppFunction('
+ NumericVector invert(NumericVector& x) {
+     x = x + 1;
+     return x;
+ }')
> invert(1:3)
[1] 2 3 4
```

Rcpp sugar is convenient, but presumably inefficient, because it creates a new object and assigns it instead of modifying the original one in-place. Intuitively, I attempted to do a `x += 1;`, but Rcpp complains

> error: no viable overloaded '+='

How can I use Rcpp sugar to perform in-place modification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong -- no copies are made [1]. So just do it in-place:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("void inplaceMod(NumericVector x) { x = x + 1; }")
R> x <- as.numeric(1:5)
R> inplaceMod(x)
R> x
[1] 2 3 4 5 6
R>
```

So for your question:

> How can I use Rcpp sugar to perform in-place modification?

the answer is 'just use it as is' but pay attention to your object types.  If you do, then the *most efficient access possible* is offered by direct and seamless access to the R object memory.

[1] One known and documented caveat is when a silent cast occurs. The above would not work with `1:5` as those are *integers* which get copied to numeric first as we have `NumericVector` in the function signature. See the [Rcpp FAQ, Question 5.1](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) and other places for more on this one.